# Best practices - Delete links with Symfony 2

Tags: php, rest, symfony

In Symfony 2, which is the best way to create a link to delete a record?

I can define a route to `/entity/delete` accepting only a `DELETE` method, but I don't know how to create a `DELETE` link from a template. The same goes for creating `PUT` links.

So, what do you do? Accept `GET` petition to delete a record? Is there any way to create a `DELETE` link?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anchors can fire only GET requests. And since GET requests can be cached and in some future (when you implement serious caching) might not reach your app code at all, it's a bad practice to use GET for changing anything that modifies state of your App. Here is what I do in my projects. With these two, you will be able to just do the following in your templates:

```
<a href="{{ path('my_entity_destroy') }}" {{ delete_link(myEntity) }}>Delete</a>
```

#### How it works

Assuming your entity delete path is: `/my_entity`, methods: [DELETE]

Principle is really simple. `delete_link` extension method will create `data-attribute` on anchor, so compiled anchor will look like this:

```
<a href="/my_entity" data-delete-link="3964">Delete</a>
```

Then, when somebody clicks on that link, javascript will catch that click, create a form and fire a DELETE request with id provided in `data-delete-link` attribute.

#### What makes it work

Here is what makes it possible, a `LinkHelper` Twig extension:

```
<?php

namespace Me\MyBundle\Twig;

class LinkHelperExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('delete_link', [$this, 'fnDeleteLink'], ['is_safe' => ['all']]),
        ];
    }

    public function fnDeleteLink($target)
    {
        if (is_object($target)) {
            $target = $target->getId();
        }
        return "data-delete-link='$target'";
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'link_helper';
    }
}
```

And I a JavaScript in my base template:

```
$(function () {
    var createForm = function (action, data) {
        var $form = $('<form action="' + action + '" method="POST"></form>');
        for (input in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(input)) {
                $form.append('<input name="' + input + '" value="' + data[input] + '">');
            }
        }

        return $form;
    };

    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-delete-link]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);

        var $form = createForm($this.attr('href'), {
            id: $this.attr('data-delete-link'),
            _method: 'DELETE'
        }).hide();

        $('body').append($form); // Firefox requires form to be on the page to allow submission
        $form.submit();
    });
});
```

#### Limitations

It only works for entities that have primary key named `id`. However, you can pretty easy modify this to suit your needs and support composite primary keys etc.

Comment: Very interesting answer! Thank you for this code, I'll use immediately.

Comment: I don't know why, but your javascript code doesn't work. I'm testing it with Firefox 24 & jquery 1.11.0, and when I click on a link it does nothing. The link generated is: "<a href="/gexp/instit/delete" data-delete-link='143'>Delete</a>", and jquery and your js function is included after these links. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hah, it looks like Firefox doesn't let you submit a form if it doesn't exist in page body! Good catch! I updated javascript code to make it work in firefox too!

Comment: You have small error in your example code `<a href="{{ path('my_entity_destroy' }}" {{ delete_link(myEntity) }}>Delete</a>` should be `<a href="{{ path('my_entity_destroy') }}" {{ delete_link(myEntity) }}>Delete</a>`

Comment: Is this a best practice to rely on JS for such a basic task (Entity manipulation) ?

Comment: @Trix If you want to have `<a>` tags fire DELETE method requests, then there is no other way. Alternatively, you can create forms, but without JS, you have to use `<button>` in order to submit it.

Comment: Tnx but I think u should add use of JS to the limitations part, as that is a real limitation

Comment: 1) in deleteAction (created by default with doctrine:generate:crud) `$form->isSubmitted()`, `$form->isValid()` both always `false`. Could you please add advice? 
2) also what is `path('my_entity_destroy')` Does path contain id?

Comment: Really like this approached. I'll start using it

Answer (score 16):

**Symfony2** `_method` functionality description can be found in [How to Define Route Requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html). Below is the solution  I use.

**Link**

```
<a
    href="{{ path('my_delete_route_name', {'id': some_entity.id}) }}"
    class="as-form"
    data-method="delete"
    data-csrf="_token:{{ csrf }}"
>{{ 'delete'|trans({}, 'button') }}</a>
```

**Re-Format the above link to inline after copy-paste**

Attach onClick event listener:

**JS**

```
$('.as-form').on('click',function(){
    var $form = $('<form/>').hide();

    //form options
    $form.attr({
        'action' : $(this).attr('href'),
        'method':'post'
    })

    //adding the _method hidden field
    $form.append($('<input/>',{
        type:'hidden',
        name:'_method'
    }).val($(this).data('method')));

    //adding a CSRF if needs
    if ($(this).data('csrf'))
    {
        var csrf = $(this).data('csrf').split(':');
        $form.append($('<input/>',{
            type:'hidden',
            name:csrf[0]
        }).val(csrf[1]));
    }

    //add form to parent node
    $(this).parent().append($form);

    $form.submit();

    return false;
});
```

**Controller**

```
class MyCustomController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("/delete/{id}",name="my_delete_route_name")
    * @Method("DELETE")
    * @ParamConverter("entity", class="MyEntityClass")
    * @CsrfProtector(intention="my_csrf_intention", name="_token")
    */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $entity)
    {
        // do whatever you need
    }
}
```

**Note**

`@CsrfProtector` is my custom annotation that is used to validate the CSRF token passed in request before running the controller method.

Comment: Just to add a direct link to the configuration: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http-method-override

Answer (score 3):

These solutions don't work without JavaScript enabled. If you just need a "Delete Button" in your Edit-Form it would be also possible to create a second submit with delete name and redirect in the updateAction in your Controller to the deleteAction if the "delete-submit" was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the advice of Bernhard Zürn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29181933/6154476), **see how to do delete link without javascript** :

1) In your form builder, add a second submit button.

```
$builder
    // ... [other fields] ...

    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
        'attr'      => array('class' => 'button-link save'),
        'label'     => 'Validate'
    ))
    ->add('delete', SubmitType::class, array(
        'attr'      => array('class' => 'button-link delete'),
        'label'     => 'Delete'
    ));
```

2) In your twig template, show the delete button wherever you want. In this example, I use the same form to add and edit a user. So, I put the code in an 'if' condition to detect edit action.

```
{% if user_id is defined %}
    {{ form_widget(form.delete) }}
{% endif %}
```

3) In your controller, use the button's `isClicked()` method for querying if the "delete" button was clicked:

```
   /**
    * @Route("/users/edit/{id}", name="user_edit")
    */
   public function editAction($id, Request $request) {    
      // get user from database
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);

      // user doesn't exist
      if (!$user) {
         throw $this->createNotFoundException('No user found for id '. $id);
      }

      // build the form with user data
      $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

      // form POST
      $form->handleRequest($request);
      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

         /*** SAVE ***/
         if ($form->get('save')->isClicked()) {
           // ... perform some action    

         /*** DELETE ***/
         } elseif ($form->get('delete')->isClicked()) {
            $em->remove($user);
            $em->flush();

            // message
            $this->addFlash('notice', "User has been deleted successfully !");

            // show list
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user');
         }
      }

      // show form
      return $this->render('users/form.html.twig', array(
         'form'    => $form->createView(),
         'user_id' => $id
      ));
   }
```

To make further progress, you can add a confirm message `Are you sure you want to delete this user ?` in javascript before executing route action.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea. You are breaking the "single responsability" rule on the controller, because a single action (/edit/{id}) does THREE jobs, show an item to be modified, modify an entity and delete an entity. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Don't let the downvotes get you down - I thought your solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!