# Symfony 2 - redirection after a delete action goes to wrong URL

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a project in Symfony 2, and I have inside a view a link which calls a delete form; I followed [Best practices - Delete links with Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747685/best-practices-delete-links-with-symfony-2), to deal with this case, and it has worked, but the problem that I have is that, when I use redirect in the end of the action, I get the following problem:

The redirect goes to

`/Stock/boncommande/27/boncommande`

but I want it to be

`/Stock/boncommande`

Here is the code of the different parts involved:

*Controller/Action*

```
/**
 * Deletes a Boncommande entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="boncommande_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 * 
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('StockStockBundle:Boncommande')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Boncommande entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("boncommande"));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Boncommande entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id) {
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
                    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('boncommande_delete', array('id' => $id)))
                    ->setMethod('DELETE')
                    ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
                    ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

*Routing file*

```
    #bon de commande
boncommande:
    pattern:  /boncommande
    defaults: { _controller: StockStockBundle:Boncommande:index }
boncommande_delete:
    pattern: /boncommande/{id}/delete
    defaults: {_controller: StockStockBundle:Boncommande:delete}
    requirements:
        _method:  POST|GET
```

*Link in view*

```
<a href="{{path('boncommande_delete', { 'id': entity.idbc })}}" id="stock_stockbundle_annuler" class="as-form btn red"
                       data-method="delete"> Annuler</a>
```

*JQuery code*

```
$('.as-form').on('click',function(){

            var $form = $('<form/>').hide();

            //form options
            $form.attr({
                'action' : $(this).attr('href'),
                'method':'post'
            })

            //adding the _method hidden field
            $form.append($('<input/>',{
                type:'hidden',
                name:'_method'
            }).val($(this).data('method')));



            //add form to parent node
            $(this).parent().append($form);

            $form.submit();

            return false;
           });
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Can I just check, is the (wrong) URL it goes to `/Stock/boncommande/27/boncommande` and not `/Stock/boncommande/27/delete`?  What you're seeing looks like a weird combination of the two routes.  Is your routing completely normal in other ways?

Comment: Might be worth checking the Routing pane of the debug toolbar to see what Symfony is doing there

Comment: Why do you use @Route annotation if you load routing through the file? How do you load the bundle routing (could you show main routing.yml file?)?

Comment: boncommande/37/delete ; and the exception says that MethodNotAllowedHttpException: No route found for "GET /Stock/boncommande/37/delete": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

Comment: I removed the annotation but still the problem persist

Comment: (frumious) yes in other cases its normal, how can I check the routing pane ?

Comment: If you've got the web toolbar showing (default for dev environment) open it up and it's the tab with the signpost icon, screenshot here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#working-with-environments

Comment: it's not shown , i see just the code of exception

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think you'd normally have the toolbar (if Symfony handles the exception nicely, which it should), but oh well.  So you click `Annuler`, which (correctly) goes to `/Stock/boncommande/37/delete` (via POST), your Action runs, and then you're redirected to `/Stock/boncommande/37/delete` again (via GET), and you get that exception?  Is that right?  Is your Action definitely executing?

Comment: Why do you have `createDeleteForm($id)`?  Is the form it creates used in the view?

Comment: no I think it's called via the delete method

Comment: I work with the generated action by the crud generation cmd

Comment: pleaz I need help !!!!

Comment: I relized that it's working on mozilla but on google chrome, I get an exception

Comment: In that case it's probably to do with the way JQuery is creating the real HTML form and submitting it.  Maybe try hard-coding the form into the View just to see if it works without JQuery?

Comment: The problem is that I have form inside a form, I got confused, I don't know waht I've to do

Comment: I have the same issue with my own code - found a fix? After sending a DELETE request to an entity, and performing a redirect, it's STILL a delete request.